# MyBatis+OSGi: how to remove mappers dynamically

Tags: java, orm, osgi, mybatis, ibatis

I have and OSGi architecture and I use xml mappers+interfaces (as it's recommended).

Mybatis configuration file I put in glassfish/domains/domain1/config folder. This configuration is loaded when MyBatisConnectionFactory is called first time. That's ok.

Now every bundle has its own mappers. I can add them dynamically by putting

com.acme.myproject.MyMapper and com/acme/myproject/MyMapper.xml into relative folders and having in Activator

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    getSqlSessionFactory().getConfiguration().addMapper(MyMapper.class);
}
```

It seems to work. When my bundle starts mappers are added to configuration. The problem is that if I update bundle changes are not taken into effect till I restart my glassfish domain. As I understand I must firstly remove previous mappers but can't find the way to do it. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was opened as a `MyBatis` issue years ago and closed as **won't-fix**, but they did provide a workaround: http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=98.

The code link doesn't work, but the conceptual workaround remains, and the file in question can likely be tracked down within `log4j`.

Here is one place where the code is stored, which appears it's from `Maven Central`:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog.java

In short, they recommend:

> You just need to reload your `SqlSessionFactory` calling the
>   `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build` when you detect the file has changed.

Answer (score 1):

BundleActivator also has a stop() method which gets called when a bundle stops, but that won't work because iBatis/MyBatis doesn't seem to have a removeMapper() method or equivalent - which means that the only way to dynamically remove mappings is to shut it down and restart it...

Comment: This case we loose all advantages of osgi. Is there no any way?

Comment: It's a conceptual impedance mismatch between MyBatis and OSGi; what I'd suggest is to create a service that keeps track of MyBatis configuration wraps MyBatis and restarts just MyBatis (if that is even possible) when the configuration changes.